# @FXMLViewFlowContext Null pointer exception

Tags: java, javafx, control-flow, viewflow

I want to create a JavaFX Application for my client. I found DataFX framework and like it. But I have problem with `@FXMLViewFlowContext` because it returns `null` each time when I call child fview from my parent. I used lib version 8.0.7 and below codes

1. I create side view in my main controller with i18n resource:

   ```
   // side controller will add links to the content flow
   Flow sideMenuFlow = new Flow(SideMenuController.class);
   sideMenuFlowHandler = new FlowHandler(sideMenuFlow, context, Common.getViewConfiguration());
   drawer.setSidePane(sideMenuFlowHandler.start(new AnimatedFlowContainer(Duration.millis(320), ContainerAnimations.SWIPE_LEFT)));
   ```
2. and this my side pane controller

   ```
   @FXMLController(value = "/res/fxml/test.fxml")
   public class SideMenuController {
       @FXMLViewFlowContext
       private ViewFlowContext context;


       @FXML
       private JFXListView test;


       @FXML
       @ActionTrigger("suppliers")
       private JFXButton suppliers;


       @FXML
       @ActionTrigger("history")
       private JFXButton history;


       @FXML
       @ActionTrigger("barcode")
       private JFXButton barcode;


       @FXML
       @ActionTrigger("settings")
       private JFXButton settings;


       @FXML
       @ActionTrigger("report")
       private JFXButton report;


       @FXML
       @ActionTrigger("users")
       private JFXButton users;


       @FXML
       @ActionTrigger("inventory")
       private JFXButton inventory;


       @FXML
       @ActionTrigger("shops")
       private JFXButton shops;


       @FXML
       @ActionTrigger("calculation")
       private JFXButton calculation;


       @PostConstruct
       public void initialize(){
           test.propagateMouseEventsToParent();
           System.out.println(context);


           FlowHandler contentFlowHandler = (FlowHandler) context.getRegisteredObject("ContentFlowHandler");
           Flow contentFlow = (Flow) context.getRegisteredObject("ContentFlow");
           bindNodeToController(suppliers, SuppliersController.class, contentFlow, contentFlowHandler);
           bindNodeToController(inventory, InventoryController.class, contentFlow, contentFlowHandler);
           bindNodeToController(users, UsersController.class, contentFlow, contentFlowHandler);
           bindNodeToController(history, HistoryController.class, contentFlow, contentFlowHandler);
           bindNodeToController(shops, ShopsController.class, contentFlow, contentFlowHandler);
           bindNodeToController(report, ReportController.class, contentFlow, contentFlowHandler);
           bindNodeToController(barcode, BarcodeController.class, contentFlow, contentFlowHandler);
           bindNodeToController(calculation, CalculationController.class, contentFlow, contentFlowHandler);
           bindNodeToController(settings, SettingsController.class, contentFlow, contentFlowHandler);
       }


       private void bindNodeToController(Node node, Class<?> controllerClass, Flow flow, FlowHandler flowHandler) {
           flow.withGlobalLink(node.getId(), controllerClass);
           node.setOnMouseClicked((e) -> {
               try {
                   flowHandler.handle(node.getId());
               } catch (Exception e1) {
                   e1.printStackTrace();
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

When I run my program I get a `NullPointerException` because the context is never injected. I searched but did not find any solution. Also I try old libraries but does not help.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved my problem. There are two reasons for this problem.
1. The first one is related to **DataFX** library version. 
2. The second problem is **initialize** mehtod. When **DataFX** is start to create controller class instance **initialize** method will be called by javafx **FXMLLoader.load()** method and this happen before init **ViewFlowContext** so that I got **NullPointerException**. In other word if you use **@PostConstruct** annotation and call your method with name **initialize**, like me, your method will be called two times one is when new controller class instance created(context has not init yet) and other one is when **@PostConstruct** method will be invoked(context has created). This correct for **DataFX flow lib 8.0b8** version. I checked this version **lib 8.0.7** but I get **NullPointerException** again. So that I changed my lib version and now everything is ok

Comment: Debugging for a while, I realized what my mistake was, which is, that you should always register context objects BEFORE calling a `flowHandler.start()` method.

Comment: I tried to add register it before `flowHandler.start` like you but not working `context.register("model",mymodel);`  and also returned by null